# Tools to measure website size

Tags: web, measurement

Can someone please recommend some tools that would help me measure the size of our website pages? I need to gather the size of the page rendered. We have over 100 pages and so obviously I am looking for a tool that could diagnose an entire domain or folder. I don't want to spend days measuring the pages one at a time.

Thank you so much in advance.

ac

Comment: Size as in, dimensions? Or as in, file size?

Comment: I want to hear from those developers that HAVE BEEN USING such tools for a good while. I don't want any recommendations from people that have never MEASURED their website. I could obviously go out and google some tools but I'd rather hear from people that have used tools to measure their website.

Comment: sorry....FILE SIZE.....we are trying to keep our pages under a certain size restriction. If we find a page that is rendering too much, we will have to divide that page into separate entities. Thank you.

Comment: google chrome? under inspect/network you should fine proper tools...

Answer (score 6):

Page Speed Insights [command-line tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/psi) gives you various metrics including `CSS size`, `HTML size` and `Image size`.

Install it with:

```
sudo npm install -g psi
```

And use it like so:

```
$ psi https://robinwinslow.uk

--------------------------------------------------------

URL:       robinwinslow.uk
Strategy:  mobile
Speed:     84
Usability: 99

CSS size                                   | 118.93 kB
HTML size                                  | 61.03 kB
Image size                                 | 5.36 kB
JavaScript size                            | 45.1 kB
CSS resources                              | 1
Hosts                                      | 4
JS resources                               | 2
Resources                                  | 6
Static resources                           | 4
Total size of request bytes sent           | 945 B

Leverage browser caching                   | 1.49
Minify CSS                                 | 0.08
Minify HTML                                | 0.06
Minimize render blocking resources         | 16
Size tap targets appropriately             | 0.11

--------------------------------------------------------
```