# Firefox / IE tools for measuring the DOM of a web page?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, dojo

My team has an existing web app, which is using some Dojo code but isn't fully "Dojo-ified" -- no custom widgets, and our AJAX calls tend to fully refresh the content pane with completely regenerated HTML, rather than just getting JSON data and updating the DOM in-place.

As part of a POC effort, a few of my teammates and I have refactored a part of our code to be "fully Dojo" -- XHR calls invoke RESTful services that return JSON, and everything is run through custom templated Dojo widgets we've created.

We need to measure the impact of this change in multiple ways -- improvements in request / response times, page load timings, and client-side effects such as differences in memory usage.

I'm trying to find some browser tools to measure the size of the generated DOM for each code base, so we can verify we're not massively increasing the memory footprint by going "full Dojo" or otherwise potentially impacting client-side performance. I found a couple of postings related to this ( [Tools to measure website size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859427/tools-to-measure-website-size) and [Tool to measure all (js)objects in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752425/tool-to-measure-all-jsobjects-in-a-webpage)), but they both suggested the use of Chrome's tools and nothing else.

Are there any tools for the other major browsers (Firefox, IE 7/8, and Safari)? Or is Chrome the only one that has such a tool?

Answer (score 2):

IE8+ [profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd565629%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Firefox [profiler](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)

Safari [profiler](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/1Introduction/Introduction.html)

Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Firebug is no good (at least Firbug 1.7.3 on Firefox 3.6) -- it has a DOM tab, but it only gives the list of objects without giving total memory usage. None of the other tabs that I see in Firebug give a memory breakdown either. I can't upgrade to a newer version of Firefox / Firebug, as our company has set Firefox 3.6 as the standard and we have to test on that as the baseline.

Comment: @JLMoran - Firebug has a *massive* number of add-ons, so even if it doesn't do what you want out of the box, there may well be something you can use with it that will work for you.

Comment: Wanted to add more, but the Return key submits the comment... The IE 8 profiler tab in the Dev Tools window (F12) also doesn't show memory usage, just the call tree and functions list. Safari's profiler tool is the same way, and as with Firebug the other Web Inspector tabs don't show memory usage. I had already checked these, which is why I was asking the question here.

Comment: also, re standardising on FF3.6. That's fair enough, but you also need to test on the latest version too; just because it works on FF3.6, doesn't mean you can just assume it's perfect in FF6. Same goes for the other browsers; you need to test in all relevant versions, not just your baseline.

Comment: @Spudley, I totally agree with testing on the newest versions, at least normally. But we almost exclusively deal with enterprise clients, who as you've probably heard aren't the fastest to upgrade anything. ;-)

We may have some testers in our QA department who have a newer version of FF installed for forward compatibility testing, but the mandate for the dev team is that we can't upgrade our copy of Firefox to 4 or later (much though I'd like to). :-(

Comment: @JLMoran - it is possible to run multiple versions of FF simulaneously. See http://msujaws.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/running-multiple-versions-of-firefox-simultaneously/ I would also say that regardless of your clients' *current* version requirments, you should still be forward testing, because if you don't, they'll be upset when they do decide to upgrade and bugs in your app prevents them from doing so.

Comment: @Spudley - Thanks for that link! I've got FF6 installed now, which means I can also use Firebug 1.8 with its memory profiling tool. I've also used the profiler in Chrome as suggested in those other posts I linked to, and it's definitely nice. I'm surprised that Chrome has this and Safari doesn't, since it's clearly the same underlying tool from WebKit. Google must have added that in the private fork they use for Chrome.

Comment: @JLMoran Safari and Chrome also tend to ship different versions of webkit